# Connect to FaceBook Via Mobile WebSite in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, mobile-website

I am developing an Android app in which I will open up a Mobile Website in a WebView. But Some of the Controls will be there in App due to which Website responds. So now my issue is that I need to Connect to Facebook from Mobile Website not from the app. So fb integration has to be done from Web Side or else from App side. I don't have any ideas on this kind of thing but my client said to do so. I am not confident but sure that it cannot be happen from app side as it is Mobile Website. Any Help in this regard would be appreciated.